# Dynamically update and compile SCSS with PHP on database update

Tags: php, css, sass

Hello 
I'm here for counseling as I'm currently re-designing my website to add a user-interface which will allow me to edit it's architecture and content anywhere and whenever I want.
(I know there is already CMS or Frameworks made to ease the development but I'm trying to learn the "how to" and methods of development before jumping that step.)

I designed my website stylesheet using SASS/Compass which output me a clean CSS file.
 In this css I have some icons classes generated using SASS loop, they have the same attributes but the background.

```
$icon-list: aftereffect, photoshop, illustrator;

@each $icon in $icon-list {
    .#{$icon} {
        background-image: url("../icons/JPEG/#{$icon}.jpg");
    }
}
```

The "$icon-list"s content which was static is now stored in a table to be dynamic, I wish to add and remove entries freely without manually editing and producing again and again. 
So my question here is : How can I do to generate the icon classes only when there is an update in the icon's table ? What's the best way to do it ?

Those are the two mains solution I came with:

- I think it's possible to compile SCSS with PHP, I could edit the icon's SCSS file, then replace the $icon-list variable's content and compile scss whenever I'd issue an add/remove request with php on the icon table. But I'm not too sure of how to do it.
- Always when an add/remove request would be issued, I could generate the new icons classes with php and stack them to the bottom of the main stylesheet. But then I'd have to search and remove the previous classes, because It wouldn't erase the previous styles and I wish to keep only one css file.

I hope you will be able to help and counsel me on which methods are the best and if you have a better way to do it. I'm not asking for snippets of code because I really wish to develop myself and learn but If there is a need for it, to explain something then be it. I'm really sorry for seeming exigent and for my bad english as I'm not a native speaker.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you might be approaching this the wrong way.  Unless your images live inside the database rather than the file system, the fact that some of the data exists in the database (for foreign key purposes, etc.) is irrelevant.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558811/import-sass-file-from-database-instead-of-filesystem and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549069/get-sass-from-database-compile-passed-data-instead-of-reading-from-file

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My files lives on the file system. But I can't see how the two questions are related to my case. When I spoke about compiling SCSS, I meant in real time when a database add/rm request would be issued by using a php-SCSS compiler. The two questions seems to concern production compilation using ruby's command.