# Sass dynamic colors with PHP

Tags: php, sass

I want to add support in my Admin Panel for change layout default color. Example:

```
$color: #333; // I will get this color from DB
background-color: $color
```

I read a bit about Sass and I can do that using it? I don't want to create 7 `style.css` with different colors set.

It's possible? I know that I can create "style.php" and set Content-header CSS, but I'm not like this way.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558811/import-sass-file-from-database-instead-of-filesystem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549069/get-sass-from-database-compile-passed-data-instead-of-reading-from-file

Answer (score 3):

Things like SASS and LESS are CSS pre-processors meaning you can use variables in them, but they are processed and you include the newly output CSS file in your HTML.

For what you are are trying to accomplish, you can utilize server side variables to override CSS. I personally find techniques like this messy, but it will work for what you are trying to accomplish.

So for example, if you designed your layout to have this CSS:

```
.myBlock {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

And you included it in your HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mylayout.css">
```

Following that, you could then use PHP to dynamically build an override:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mylayout.css">
<style>  
   <?php
       $overrides = ['.myBlock' => 'background-color: blue;'];
       foreach ($overrides as $class => $css) {
          echo($class.' {'.$css.'}');
       }
   ?>
</style>
```

The rendered HTML after the server side processing would look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mylayout.css">
<style>
    .myBlock {background-color: blue;}
</style>
```

Due to the nature of CSS, this is the last rule defined so will be what the browser uses.

---

Another approach, and probably the more clean approach, is to use JSON and Javascript. You can take the array of data on the server side using PHP and JSON encode it to be echoed out. Then using Javascript, you can apply the color. For example:

```
<script>
   var colors = <?php echo(json_encode($colorData)); ?>;
   $('.myElement').css('background-color', colors['myElement']);
</script>
```